# Bad resolution in 12.10 after upgrade from 12.04

Tags: upgrade, 12.10, resolution

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 and the max display resolution is only 1024 x 768. In 12.04 it was 1680 x 1060 and working fine. I have a Samsung SyncMaster 225BW Display and a Graphic card: GeForce GTX 550 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 on a Intel® Core™ i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8  64 bits. How do I get my resolution back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you havent installed your graphics drivers for your nvidia card still.. install them from Additional Drivers ..and retry to set your resolution

Type in terminal 
command  : sudo nvidia-settings

Comment: How and from where do I install them or check if I have them already.

Comment: try to run nvidia-settings in terminal if it exists then nvidia settings window will open !! thats it

Comment: Thanks a lot that help using  "sudo nvidia-settings" it is working now and sorry my bad English